# It's possible to add/load an exploded war to a stand-alone java app?

Tags: java, classpath, war

First the main problem:

We've a web application in tomcat that overloads and shut down when the system tries to send e-mails at 12 o'clock. At first it was just hundreds of them (and the server behaved well) but now it's thousands and runs out of everything.

We want to "run" these jobs in a different JVM. For that purpose I've been asked to **create a stand alone app that loads Spring and hibernate context and call the methods that sends the e-mails and sms; and runs this via command line**. But they want to use the same "war" that resides in the tomcat's server (avoiding any kind of replication).

[image]

I've created the application via Eclipse and when I hit run, it does its magic. But when I try to run it via command line I get a NoClassDefFoundError, Obviouly, thanks to a ClassPath reference problem. I've tried to put the path to the "WEB-INF" directory w/o success. We don't care to kill portability if that mean running this app.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\bin>java -jar -cp ".;D:\powerfollowups\trunk\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\*;D:\powerfollowups\trunk\WebContent\WEB-INF\clases" D:\powerfollowups\workspace\PFUReportSender\target\pwrFU-2.jar
```

I also tried to put it in the manifest's Class-Path, like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.powerfollowups.StandAlonePFUReportSender
Class-Path: D:\powerfollowups\trunk\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\* D:\powerfollowups\trunk\WebContent\WEB-INF\clases
```

**How do I add all this in to the classpath?**

Optimize the code it's not an option rigth now.

Comment: Show us how you run it via command line.

Comment: Make a queue in a database lists all emails, then process them in batches?

Comment: @dlp I make that suggestion, (to do it in batches), it didn't transcended... :(. We are triying to load ALL the e-mails in memory, eventually this not gonna work either. If they load them in batches of, for example, 500 mails, it could go better.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Any thougs? the CLASSPATH only accept jar files? or either absolute paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a few things on the classpath:

- WEB-INF/classes - This contains all your custom classes from the WAR
- All the jars of libraries that your classes from your WAR dependent upon
- All the jars your command-line application is dependent upon

edit: based upon your updated question

```
java -jar -cp ".;D:\powerfollowups\trunk\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\*;D:\powerfollowups\trunk\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes"  D:\powerfollowups\workspace\PFUReportSender\target\pwrFU-2.jar
```

Comment: How do I add all this in to the classpath?

Comment: I've updated my response from the additional data in your question.

Comment: this didn't work. :( it is possible to load "resources" to the classpath that aren't in a jar file?

Comment: any individual `.class` file can be added

Comment: @codelark For some reason, that I don't yet understand, with the -jar option it doesn't work, but if I add the pwrFU.jar in the classpath and call the main class, it works. java -classpath D:\powerfollowups\workspace\PFUReportSender\target\pwrFU-2.jar;D:\powerfollowups‌​\trunk\WebContent\WEB-INF\*;D:\powerfollowups\trunk\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes;D:‌​\powerfollowups\trunk\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\* com.powerfollowups.StandAlonePFUReportSender